# override :host css in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

how can i override :host css

```
:host {
--width: 304px;
--min-width: auto;
--max-width: auto;
--height: 100%;
--min-height: auto;
--max-height: auto;
--background: var(--ion-background-color, #fff); // <-- i want to shut this down
inset: 0px;
display: none;
position: absolute;
contain: strict;
```

}

PS. this css is on ion-content

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to change the `:host` CSS to change the background of `ion-content`. You can add this to your CSS

```
ion-content{
    --ion-background-color:#111D12; // Or whatever color you want
}
```

But if you really want to change `:host` CSS, then you can add this in your global CSS file.

```
:host {
    --background: none; // or whatever color you want
}
```

Comment: got the idea, Thanks

Comment: is the :host selector something from css? or is it custom to ionic?

Comment: Its a pseudo-class in CSS, more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()